# How to solve Blocked by CORS policy Error Flutter

Tags: .net, flutter, dart, cors

I am using flutter to create a web application, I got this error while accessing the API I don't know what is going wrong I am using .NET for backend which is connected with SAP for data. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API_URL'
> from origin 'http://localhost:64848' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my code :

```
await DioUtil.getInstance()
      .post(
    apiUrl,
    options: Options(
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true, "Accept": "*/*"},
    ),
    data: body,
  )
      .then((value) {
    
      debugPrint("Status Code == " + value.statusCode.toString());
      
      } else {
        tryAgainDialog(getContractFullReport);
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

I am using interceptor with basic auth for authorization to backend.

Comment: What does your .NET code look like? Access control needs to be specified there, not in your client code.

Comment: I haven't specified much in .NET Cors policy, do you know any reference how it should be.

Comment: Please indicate which software from SAP it connects, the SAP tag itself should not be used (ambiguous). Thank you. (although probably the issue is not related to the connected software)

Comment: Yes, also thing it is not related to SAP at all, 
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH"));
This is the code I have in my webcofig file to setup Cors for API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure CORS properly on your server side.

Since you did not post any code, I can only suggest you look at [Microsofts Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0) how to do this. This is the latest, if you are using older version, they are available, too.

Comment: config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH"));
this is how i am setting up cors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this run command:
**flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"**

If you are using *vscode*, you can add this arg to your launch.json:
{"name": , "request": "launch", "type": "dart", "args": ["--web-browser-flag=--disable-web-security"]}

Comment: this is a temporary solution my web application already in production so i need a permanent solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).